# How to get accumulated cpu times of all threads

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I have a program that runs serval hours. Is there any way to know cpu times of all threads, including threads that already died long before the process terminated.

Comment: Which language? Please specify in question and add as a tag as well.

Comment: Sorry not to clarify. It's an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the default behaviour of `time` and similar programs. In fact, it's harder to get the time spent on individual threads than getting the whole process's time.